# How do I make a node-red node that is already on a flow obey the default values of a newly-added property?

Tags: javascript, node-red

Initially, this is my node configurations.

```
RED.nodes.registerType('HelloWorld', {
  category: 'HelloWorld',
  defaults: {
    firstProp: {value: false}
  },
}
```

This `helloworld` node is then placed on a flow.

Then, I added another property, `secondProp` to the configuration and restart node-red.

```
RED.nodes.registerType('HelloWorld', {
  category: 'HelloWorld',
  defaults: {
    firstProp: {value: false}
    secondProp: {value: true}
  },
}
```

When I export the flow, I notice the `secondProp` is set to false. I had expected it to be set to the default which is `true`

```
[
{
    "id": "04abe6r5baqs16dc",
    ...
    "firstProp": false,
    "secondProp": false, //expected it to be true
    "x": 290,
    "y": 360
}
]
```

May I know how do I resolve this and ensure the existing custom nodes on the flow obey the default values of a newly-added property?

NOTE:

When I pull the custom node and place it on the flow, it doesn't have this issue i.e., the `secondProp` value is `true`.

Comment: That isn't the expected behaviour and could be a bug. Can you raise an issue on github so we can investigate it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the node-red maintainer [commented](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/3640#issuecomment-1150791279)

> The flow file is not modified just because you modified the custom node src. You would have to handle any in-place upgrades in `oneditprepare`. This is normal behaviour as far as I can see.

So as a workaround, we can only do like this

```
RED.nodes.registerType('HelloWorld', {
  category: 'HelloWorld',
  defaults: {
    firstProp: {value: false}
  },
  oneditprepare: {
    if (this.secondProp === undefined) {
      this.secondProp = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will require us to open the edit dialog of the node for it to take effect.